# Getting value between same characters XSLT - XML

Tags: xml, xslt

MY XML CODE IS :

```
 <cbc:Note> Yalnız : #KırkYedi TL Doksan KRŞ#</cbc:Note>
```

HOW CAN I GET THE VALUE (KırkYedi TL Doksan KRŞ) BETWEEN # AT XSLT ?

I could come this far and stuck here.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//n1:Invoice/cbc:Note">
    <xsl:if test="contains(.,'Yalnız :')">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'Yalnız : #')"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I am open to any kind solution as long as it is suitable for xslt. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> HOW CAN I GET THE VALUE (KırkYedi TL Doksan KRŞ) BETWEEN # AT XSLT ?

By using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '#'), '#')"/>
```

Or, if you know more about the prefix:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'Yalnız : #'), '#')"/>
```